# Proving 2SAT is in P vs algorithm for finding a satisfying assignment

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, satisfiability, polynomial-time, p-vs-np

I want to understand the proof in the following [link](https://www.iitg.ac.in/deepkesh/CS301/assignment-2/2sat.pdf) that 2SAT is in P. What is the need for the last corollary? Wouldn't be enough to just prove the case for the graph with the help of the path search?

Furthermore, is the proof for the corollary correct? The algorithm is presented there without proof.

Comment: "The same graph construction can be used to construct a satisfying assignment for $\Psi$ (if it is satisfiable)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the corollary in order to show that 2SAT is in P. Rather, it uses the same techniques to give a fast algorithm for finding a satisfying assignment for satisfiable 2CNFs.

If you're not sure whether the algorithm actually works, try proving it.